# Reset the Pinned Bottom Row Data in ag-grid Angular 8

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I used pinned bottom row data as a Footer to display the summation of rows in AG-grid, but the problem is, I cant rest the value of pinned Row *(the summation is a JSON Object contains the summation values that have been already calculated from Backend)*.

How could I resolve that **without using Aligned Grid as Footer**?

**Note:** the recived summation are not static will changed based on selected ID from drop down list

```
this._myService.getProjectSummation("",[],selected,selected).subscribe(data=>{

  this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData([]);
  this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData(JSON.parse(data));


});
```

What I did similar to this [Link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/) but in my code, the pinned raw data values are not static it will change based on selected Option from Select

Comment: Could you provide more explanation with some examples

Comment: @Shravan What I did is similar to this [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/) but I wanna the value for the same pinned raw dynamic

Comment: So you basically want the bottom pinned row to update value if the dropdown selection changes? Am I right? This dropdown is it inside AgGrid?

Comment: yes, No it's isolated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respond to the dropdown selection changes using the `change` event on `<select>` tag and then update your bottom pinned row based on your selection. I have shown this using a simple total calculation of cart items in different currencies as example.

**Template file:**

```html
<h1>Ag Grid</h1>

<select (change)="calculateTotal($event)">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let item of currency" 
    [value]="item.name"
  >{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>

<ag-grid-angular 
  style="width: 95%; height: 250px" 
  class="ag-theme-balham" 
  [columnDefs]="columns" 
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

**Component file:**

```js
  calculateTotal(event) {
    let ccyName = event.target.value;
    let ccy = this.currency.find(item => item.name === ccyName);

    this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData([
      { product: `TOTAL (in ${ccy.name})`, price: this.total * ccy.factor }
    ]);
  }
```

Full example can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhtguy) on the Stackblitz.